# Install USB Wifi to run in parallel on RPi 3+

Tags: wifi, usb, pi-3b+, internet

This is a very similar question to one already asked, but it is different in that I  want the USB dongle to provide internet access to the RPi while the RPi AP still operates.

I am trying to set up a navigation system on my boat using OpenPlotter and OpenCPN using 2 RPi 3+'s. It all works wonderfully as a standalone network, but without internet access.

I'd like to add an internet connection to provide internet access when I'm in port so that I can browse the web. SO I added a TP-Link dongle which is recognized and I can attach it to my home network using the standard process. Running ifconfig returns a local 10.10.10.1 for the local network and 192.168.abc.xyz for the home network.

But whenever I open the browser I get a connection error no matter the internet site - Google, Facebook, Amazon, ...

Clearly I must be doing something incorrectly, but I haven't a clue.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please show us the output of `sudo route -n` aka your routing table.

Comment: What is a RPi 3+? Is it a [RPi 3A+ or RPi 3B+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Generations_of_released_models)? What is this TP-Link dongle? Does it has just an ethernet port? Does your home network is available in port? Do you connect to it with an ethernet cable using the TP-Link dongle? Where is the internet connection? On the home network? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.